# Как разделить CSV файл с помощью команды split?

Tags: php, csv, split

Есть файл .CSV с названием `file.csv`в нем 20000 строк, первая заголовки. 
Как разделить его на 4 файла по 5000 строк оставляя везде первую строку (заголовок) с помощью команды split или любой другой на сервере?

Comment: Это вообще возможно?

Comment: Конечно. Только не split (оно устарело на два потопа), а explode для отделения хедера и array_chunk для деления данных на части.

Comment: @Akina А может имеется в виду именно консольный `split`?

Comment: А есть код для примера? Или обзор какой нибудь?

Comment: Нашла типа такого кода:  
`$limit      = 2000;
$dimension  = 10;
$sourcename = 'tovar.csv';
$source     = new SplFileObject($sourcename, 'r');
$source->setFlags(SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
 
$source->flock(LOCK_SH);
foreach ($source as $i => $line) {
    if ( !($i % $limit) ) {
        $j          = floor($i / $limit) + 1;
        $destname   = ( $j < $dimension ? '0' : '' ) . "$j.csv";
        $dest       = new SplFileObject($destname, 'w');
    }
 
    $dest->fwrite($line);
}
$source->flock(LOCK_UN);
 
//unset($dest, $source) // if the script continues`

Comment: но там кодировка не та, разбивает по многу

Comment: @Akina , в [первой версии вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/940170/178576) не было метки php, потому мною и был дан совет воспользоваться программой split.

Comment: В итоге ничего не получается, разбивает не по указанному кол-ву. Кодировка кракозябры.